# Difference between max length of the record vs record size limit

Tags: tls, openssl

As per [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) (TLS) the max possible length of the record is 2^14.

But I could see now a new parameter "Maximum record size limit".

Why do we have the new parameter "Maximum record size limit" since RFC 5246 already mentions Max possible length is 2^14

Comment: I can't find those values in the RFC. Where is "Maximum record size limit"?

Comment: Might be an implementation of [this extension](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6066#section-4) (IME uncommon) or [this updated one](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8449) (purportedly good for IoT)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Your right its part of extension. Ya basically my question  is it possible to have both " max_fragment_length" and "record_size_limit" Extensions at the same time. But after going through the RFC 8449 my understanding is its not possible have so.